# URL for video selected from camera roll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am able to launch camera roll from my app. I want to get the URL of the video when it is selected by a user, because I want to use it for asset reading/writing.

Is it possible to get the URL of the selected video from camera roll ? If yes, how ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to your class and use this code to retrieve the url.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
}
```

This is a good resource:[Accessing the Camera and Photo Library from an iOS 4 iPhone Application](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Accessing_the_Camera_and_Photo_Library_from_an_iOS_4_iPhone_Application)